# What should I read to deepen my understanding about 'relativism and anti-realism'?

Tags: realism, objectivity, relativism, moral-realism, anti-realism

After some discussion, I noticed the philosophical questions I want to explore are mainly ideas that take a relativist and anti-realist point of view. (whether when it comes to morals, or concepts such as Femininity)

What should I read if I want to deepen my understanding of relativism and anti-realism (as well as their opposite views)?

I want to answer questions such as:

- Is everything a social construct?
- Are some interpreted meanings more absurd than others (such as
  interpreting 'American' as a person who loves carrots vs a person who comes from America)
- What is the nature of something being 'better' or 'worse', what could be a source of giving out values of better/worse?

Which branch of philosophy should I begin with first?

Comment: As well as that Moral Relativism SEP article I posted you, I highly recommend Kurt Vonnegut's book 'Cat' s Cradle'. https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/135479.Cat_s_Cradle He makes really incisive points about how we group people into constructed categories, & why. You might like this answer on Moral Nihilism https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/79432/is-this-also-moral-nihilism/79436#79436 & this on postmodernism vs relativism https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/90506/why-is-post-modernism-so-often-equated-to-relativism-are-there-any-responses-in/90584#90584

Comment: @CriglCragl Thank you!

Comment: for such questions, it is always best to list your general background or what you have already read

Comment: @Papuseme Yes but which branch of philosophy should I explore to understand relativism/anti-realism?

Comment: well both topics are squarly in metaphysics and epistemology. Or you could be topical, since your bullet points are topical, and read on the structuralists, or phil lang, or moral relativism resp.

Comment: @Papuseme Thank you, would you suggest studying metaphysics or epistemology first to get a good grounding?

Comment: metaphysics, in particular metaethics. Skim the SEP/IEP first as it will give you a good orientation of modern thought on the subject